# c# passing class type member as parameter works as call by value

Tags: c#, call-by-value

as i know class type parameter is always passed as reference.
but whenever i pass a class type variable which is class member as parameter. it always works like
call by value.

```
public class MapGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
   [SerializeField]
    private List<MapEntity> stageTerrains = new List<MapEntity>();
    private MapEntity stageTerrain = new MapEntity();

    private void Start()
    {
        RandomChoice(stageTerrains);
    }


    public void RandomChoice(MapEntity mapEntity)
    { 
        mapEntity = stageTerrains[Random.Range(0,selectedList.Count)];
        Print(mapEntity);  //it always works well 
        Print(stageTerrain);  // always print null
    }
}
```

so i put an ref keyword to parameter and it works as call by reference

```
public class MapGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
   [SerializeField]
    private List<MapEntity> stageTerrains = new List<MapEntity>();
    private MapEntity stageTerrain = new MapEntity();

    private void Start()
    {
        RandomChoice(ref stageTerrains);
    }


    public void RandomChoice(ref MapEntity mapEntity)
    { 
        mapEntity = stageTerrains[Random.Range(0,selectedList.Count)];
        Print(mapEntity);  //it always works well 
        Print(stageTerrain);  // print well too 
    }
}
```

i wonder why passing class type member as parameter is worked like call by value

Comment: "as i know class type parameter is always passed as reference" - well it's passed *as* a reference value, but it's still passed *by* value unless you use a `ref` or `out` parameter. They're somewhat different, and it's really important to understand the difference. See https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the ref documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref)

> When used in a method's parameter list, the ref keyword indicates that an argument is passed by reference, not by value. The ref keyword **makes the formal parameter an alias** for the argument, which must be a variable.

So I'll try to explain the **makes the formal parameter an alias** as simple as possible.

### Without ref

Imagine the `stageTerrain` from `private MapEntity stageTerrain = new MapEntity();` as a box holding an address.

Imagine the `mapEntity` from `public void RandomChoice(MapEntity mapEntity)` as another **NEW** box.

- If you change a property of the mapEntity before assigning a new object, it will also change the value of the calling variable.

When you call the `RandomChoice` the `mapEntity` is a new box holding the same memory address as the `stageTerrain` box.

Now `mapEntity = stageTerrains[Random.Range(0,selectedList.Count)];` will assign the selected value only to the **New** box.

### With ref

Imagine the `mapEntity` from `public void RandomChoice(ref MapEntity mapEntity)` as an alias for an already existing box that will hold the memory reference just with a different name. (thus the alias statement)

When you call the `RandomChoice` the `mapEntity` **is the** `stageTerrain` box.